# Searching by only one part of primary key efficient?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have this table

```
Extensions

Id -> Primary Key
Number
Account
DateCreated
Etc...
```

I know that it will be very efficient to search an extension by its id like:

```
select * from Extensions where Id = 5
```

But if I have this table: (note primary key is a combination of two columns)

```
Extensions

Number -> Primary Key
Account -> Primary Key
DateCreated
Etc...
```

If that is the case will it be efficient to do?

```
select * from Extensions where Account = 'Acc1'
```

I know queries execute much faster when using a primary key. But because I am only using part of the primary key on the last query it will not execute as fast as the first query right?

Comment: Queries don't execute faster when searching for the primary key. They execute faster because of indexing, and by default the primary key is also the clustered index. What would really help here is first deciding which DBMS you are using (mysql <> sql server) and then post the create table statement including indexes and keys.

Comment: The database will maintain an index on the table by primary key.  An index can support searches on a leading subset of its columns, so the answer to your question is "it depends".  In particular, it depends on which PK column(s) your query references, and on their order in the table's PK index.

Comment: If you use `explain plan` then the database engine will tell you what it will use to access the data,

Comment: I removed the DB specific tags since they are conflicting. Feel free to add back the one you are actually using.

Comment: Just create a separate index on Account. The fact that it's part of the primary key is irrelevant aside from the fact that your dbms probably already created an index on (Number,Account) for you. It's just like any other column. It isn't very complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a composite index, the first part of the key needs to be used before the second part can be leveraged.  In the example provided, "where account='Acc1'", the primary key index will not be used because number is not referenced within the query.  Another index on account would be needed for an indexed search.

All enterprise level database engines provide a mechanism to show the execution plan (as @Ryan Vincent discusses).  I highly recommend becoming familiar with this utility in order to tune your poorly performing queries.